# Sonar infinite loop in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm invoking a standalone sonar analysis under Jenkins with these versions:

```
Jenkins: 1.529
Jenkins Sonar Plugin: 2.1
Sonar: 3.5.1
```

Sonar is using the default h2 database. When I launch a build on Jenkins, it starts correctly but go in an infinite loop at the end of the following log, I let it run for 3 days without any result... Does somebody know where it comes from?

```
[SRC] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarForJenkins2.0/bin/sonar-runner ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.1.1:9000/sonar ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project/SRC -Dsonar.language=py -Dsonar.projectName=Project -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.projectKey=Project -Dsonar.sources=server/apps/Project/
Runner configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarForJenkins2.0/conf/sonar-runner.properties
Project configuration file: NONE
Runner version: 2.0
Java version: 1.6.0_27, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS name: "Linux", version: "3.2.0-52-generic", arch: "amd64"
Default locale: "fr_FR", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
Server: http://192.168.1.1:9000/sonar
Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project/SRC/.sonar
15:29:43.167 INFO  .s.b.b.BatchSettings - Load batch settings
15:29:43.260 INFO     o.s.h.c.FileCache - User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
15:29:43.265 INFO  atchPluginRepository - Install plugins
15:29:43.640 INFO  .s.b.b.TaskContainer - -------------  Executing Project Scan
15:29:43.947 INFO  b.b.JdbcDriverHolder - Install JDBC driver
15:29:43.949 INFO  .b.ProjectExclusions - Apply project exclusions
15:29:43.952 WARN  .c.p.DefaultDatabase - H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
15:29:43.952 INFO      o.s.c.p.Database - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
15:29:44.020 INFO  actDatabaseConnector - Initializing Hibernate
15:29:45.683 INFO  .s.b.s.ScanContainer - -------------  Inspecting Project
15:29:45.687 INFO  .b.b.ProjectSettings - Load module settings
15:29:45.895 INFO  .s.b.ProfileProvider - Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=py]
15:29:45.908 INFO  s.f.ExclusionFilters - Excluded tests: 
15:29:45.908 INFO  s.f.ExclusionFilters -   **/package-info.java
15:29:45.929 INFO  nPluginsConfigurator - Configure Maven plugins
15:29:45.954 INFO        org.sonar.INFO - Compare to previous analysis (2013-09-09)
15:29:45.974 INFO        org.sonar.INFO - Compare over 5 days (2013-09-04, analysis of 2013-09-03 07:57:38.902)
15:29:45.980 INFO        org.sonar.INFO - Compare over 30 days (2013-08-10, analysis of 2013-08-12 19:34:45.97)
15:29:46.057 INFO  s.f.FileSystemLogger - Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project/SRC
15:29:46.057 INFO  s.f.FileSystemLogger - Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project/SRC/.sonar
15:29:46.057 INFO  s.f.FileSystemLogger - Source dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project/SRC/server/apps/Project
15:29:46.057 INFO  s.f.FileSystemLogger - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: fr_FR
15:29:46.096 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.python.PythonSourceImporter@549b6976...
15:29:46.825 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.python.PythonSourceImporter@549b6976 done: 729 ms
15:29:46.825 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor PythonSquidSensor...
15:29:48.152 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor PythonSquidSensor done: 1327 ms
15:29:48.153 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor PythonXunitSensor...
15:29:48.160 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor PythonXunitSensor done: 7 ms
15:29:48.161 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor...
15:29:48.161 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor done: 0 ms
15:29:48.161 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor CpdSensor...
15:29:48.161 INFO   o.s.p.cpd.CpdSensor - SonarBridgeEngine is used
15:29:48.169 INFO  s.p.c.i.IndexFactory - Cross-project analysis disabled
15:29:48.497 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor CpdSensor done: 336 ms
15:29:48.497 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProfileSensor...
15:29:48.522 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProfileSensor done: 25 ms
15:29:48.523 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
15:29:48.539 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 17 ms
15:29:48.540 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
15:29:48.543 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 3 ms
15:29:48.543 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
15:29:48.551 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 8 ms
15:29:48.984 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Execute decorators...
15:29:51.132 INFO  s.c.c.ScanGraphStore - Persist graphs of components
15:29:51.193 INFO  .b.p.UpdateStatusJob - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://192.168.1.1:9000/sonar
15:29:51.194 INFO  b.p.PostJobsExecutor - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
15:29:51.213 INFO  b.p.PostJobsExecutor - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
15:29:51.223 INFO  .p.d.p.KeepOneFilter - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2013-08-26 and 2013-09-08
15:29:51.225 INFO  .p.d.p.KeepOneFilter - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2012-09-10 and 2013-08-26
15:29:51.227 INFO  .p.d.p.KeepOneFilter - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2008-09-15 and 2012-09-10
15:29:51.230 INFO  .d.p.DeleteAllFilter - -> Delete data prior to: 2008-09-15
15:29:51.232 INFO  o.s.c.purge.PurgeDao - -> Clean Project [id=1]
15:29:51.236 INFO  o.s.c.purge.PurgeDao - <- Clean snapshot 39274
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The H2 database is for testing purpose only. Could you please move to a "real" database? See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements.

Comment: I changed to a MySQL database, it works but on the other hand the database is empty... Is it a way to transfer my custom dashboard and project snapshots (which are much more important than the dashboard) from my old h2 to the new mysql database?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to migrate data from H2 to MySQL.